# Active Directory Federation Services Token-Signing Certificate Expiration

Tags: adfs2.0, adfs

My token-signing cert is about to expire on my Microsoft ADFS server. How do I renew the self-signing cert and is there a grace period on the expired cert? That is, if the cert has failed, what are the results for single sign on (will it fail gratefully)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a very good write-up here: [AD FS 2.0: How to Replace the SSL, Service Communications, Token-Signing, and Token-Decrypting Certificates](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2554.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-replace-the-ssl-service-communications-token-signing-and-token-decrypting-certificates.aspx).

Basically, if you have AutoCertificateRollover set, ADFS will renew the certificate for you.

You then need to send the new metadata to all parties so they can update their trust with your ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the new signing cert from the ADFS metadata:

https://{{YourAdfsServerHere}}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml